# iOS : App freezes with facebook sdk and google sign in

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, google-signin

I am trying to allow user login with facebook , twitter and google . My application is old and converted from swift 3 to swift 5 . Twitter login works properly but Facebook login and Google login not work , App freezes and the screen blurs without errors like this https://youtu.be/oT4i8Es0cdI

I tried the same code with new project and it works properly . What makes old converted apps doesn't work with the same code.

I am using facebook sdk : 5.15.1
Xcode 13.3.1
Swift 5

**Code In app delegate open url:**

````
        _ app: UIApplication,
        open url: URL,
        options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]
    ) -> Bool {
        print("App open url")
        let googleDidHandle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
        let twitterHandle = TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
        let facebookDidHandle = ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            app,
            open: url,
            options: options)


        return twitterHandle || facebookDidHandle || googleDidHandle

    }
**Code for login :**
 @IBAction func loginWithFacebbok(_ sender: UIButton) {
        add(loadingViewController)

        let loginManager = FBSDKLoginKit.LoginManager()

        loginManager.logIn(permissions: [ "email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
            if error == nil{
                print("get facebook data")
                self.getFacebookData(accessToken: result?.token)

            }else{
                print("error is \(error)")
            }
        }


    }


@IBAction func loginWithGmail(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.delegate = self
        add(loadingViewController)

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
}
in App delegate
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
FirebaseApp.configure()

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
LanguageHelper.setSavedLanguage()
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            application,
            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions
        )
        return true

}```
````

Comment: if you don't give us all your code (best: reproducable example where it freezes), we can just "guess". Code freezes if it is blocked on main queue. Is you login done on main queue? Who blurs it? these are starting points to check...

Comment: I updated the question with more code , I tried the code with             DispatchQueue.main.async  but still have the same issue . I think the blur occurs when trying to open SFSafariViewController After pressing continue in switch app dialog , any help?

Comment: are you really calling ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            application,
            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions
        ) on your own? you should not do that...

Comment: No this code related to  facebook sdk , this code exist in  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started see step 4

Comment: I think the freeze causes by ios system not facebook sdk , the permission dialogue in AppAuth frame work any solution @Chris

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. The problem was in Xcode version. After updating to 13.4 everything is OK. Just try to update your Xcode.